# Migrating off Google App Engine: OAuth2Client appengine import fail

Tags: oauth2client

I am migrating a very simple app off of Google App Engine to DigitalOcean.

All the app does:  handle an AJAX request, query my BigQuery dataset, and return the response as JSON.

I am running Python 2.7, recent Django, in a virtualenv.

I have installed the Google Python Client API module, the OAuth2Client module, and a handful more.

For the life of me, I cannot import the necessary modules to successfully connect to BigQuery, and so my app that worked great on GAE fails on DigitalOcean.

```
# this works fine
import oauth2client
```

But then...

```
# this throws "global name 'appengine' is not defined"
credentials = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=_SCOPE)
```

I've tried importing appengine:

```
from oauth2client import appengine
```

But that just throws

```
No module named appengine.api
```

I have checked my lib/ dir in my virtualenv, and OAuth2Client is there.

Here is my site-packages dir in my virtualenv:

```
(app_name)root@app_name:/webapps/app_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages# l
total 1104
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 apiclient
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 bigquery-2.0.17-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   81577 May  3 00:00 bigquery_client.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   86973 May  3 00:00 bigquery_client.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   78673 May  3 00:00 bq.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   76044 May  3 00:00 bq.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 dateutil
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 discovery
drwxrwxr-x 17 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:11 django
drwxrwxr-x  2 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:11 Django-1.6.4.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     239 May  2 23:20 easy-install.pth
-rw-rw-r--  1 app_name users    126 May  2 12:10 easy_install.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 app_name users    318 May  2 12:10 easy_install.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root  104236 May  3 00:00 gflags.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   97904 May  3 00:00 gflags.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root    6977 May  3 00:00 gflags_validators.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root    7771 May  3 00:00 gflags_validators.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 google
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 google_api_python_client-1.2-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 google_apputils-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     307 May  3 00:00 google_apputils-0.4.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth
drwxrwxr-x  6 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:13 gunicorn
drwxrwxr-x  2 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:13 gunicorn-18.0-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root    4096 May  2 23:20 httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg
drwxrwxr-x  2 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:10 _markerlib
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root    4096 May  2 23:40 oauth2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  2 23:40 oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 oauth2client
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root  111741 May  2 23:20 oauth2client-1.2-py2.7.egg
drwxrwxr-x  6 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:10 pip
drwxrwxr-x  2 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:10 pip-1.5.4.dist-info
-rw-rw-r--  1 app_name users  99605 May  2 12:10 pkg_resources.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 app_name users 106608 May  2 12:10 pkg_resources.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 python_gflags-2.0-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 pytz
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x  2 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:22 setproctitle-1.1.8-py2.7.egg-info
-rwxrwxr-x  1 app_name users  53539 May  2 12:22 setproctitle.so
drwxrwxr-x  4 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:10 setuptools
drwxrwxr-x  2 app_name users   4096 May  2 12:10 setuptools-2.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root    4096 May  2 23:43 simplejson
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  2 23:43 simple_json
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  2 23:43 simple_json-1.1-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  2 23:43 simplejson-3.4.1-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   18568 May  3 00:00 table_formatter.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   25967 May  3 00:00 table_formatter.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  2 23:40 tests
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root    4096 May  3 00:00 uritemplate
```

And if I go into the **oauthclient2**, I DO see appengine.py:

```
(app_name)root@readrboard-events:/webapps/app_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client# l
total 388
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1044 May  3 00:00 anyjson.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   536 May  3 00:00 anyjson.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32524 May  3 00:00 appengine.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37284 May  3 00:00 appengine.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 44282 May  3 00:00 client.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 48404 May  3 00:00 client.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4405 May  3 00:00 clientsecrets.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4440 May  3 00:00 clientsecrets.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10233 May  3 00:00 crypt.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11970 May  3 00:00 crypt.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3833 May  3 00:00 django_orm.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5482 May  3 00:00 django_orm.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3160 May  3 00:00 file.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4291 May  3 00:00 file.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3038 May  3 00:00 gce.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3207 May  3 00:00 gce.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   213 May  3 00:00 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   416 May  3 00:00 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3227 May  3 00:00 keyring_storage.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3892 May  3 00:00 keyring_storage.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11379 May  3 00:00 locked_file.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12863 May  3 00:00 locked_file.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13935 May  3 00:00 multistore_file.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16386 May  3 00:00 multistore_file.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5548 May  3 00:00 old_run.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4981 May  3 00:00 old_run.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8344 May  3 00:00 tools.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8723 May  3 00:00 tools.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5670 May  3 00:00 util.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5853 May  3 00:00 util.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3368 May  3 00:00 xsrfutil.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2928 May  3 00:00 xsrfutil.pyc
```

1) What am I doing wrong?  Why is appengine not loading?

2) I can't find a different way to assert my credentials to the Google API, either.  How could I connect to Google APIs with my crds to query BigQuery from a non-Google App Engine server?

Answer (score 0):

The line "credentials = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=_SCOPE)" will never work outside of app engine. The App Assertion credentials are only available to apps running on app engine or with dev_appserver.

To get credentials without using app assertion, you can create a service account via the Cloud Console (https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts) and get them using oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials. Those credentials can be used wherever you had been using the app assertion credentials before.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I found references to SignedJwtAssertionCredentials after I posted this, but never managed to import a module in a way that SignedJwtAssertionCredentials was defined.  Must be operator error, but I would get errors trying to use that, too.  I ended up switching approaches entirely, using Node and the bigquery package.  All's well, now.

Comment: In case you go back to python, SignedJwtAssertionCredentials are only available if you have PyOpenSSL installed. The way you find out that something is wrong (SignedJwtAssertionCredentials doesn't exist as a class unless you've got PyOpenSSL) leaves something to be desired.